# Daylight saving time with NSTimeZone best practice

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimezone

I have created a weekly view(similar to calendar) with header day of week. I am creating the current time using below code :

```
+(NSDate *) getCurrentDate {

    NSDate* datetime = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/Juneau"];// this is dynamic and coming from server.
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone]; // Prevent adjustment to user's local time zone.
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
    NSString* dateTimeInIsoFormatForUserTimeZone = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:datetime];  
    return [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateTimeInIsoFormatForUserTimeZone];

}
```

I am using this date as reference to create week date (from monday to sunday). My code work fine for all case but I was failing at DST time zone.

I have seen similar question on stack-overflow but they are more subjective and not able to solve my problem. Answer with code and best practise is highly appreciated. Thanks In advance!.

Comment: Why would you need to do date > string > date?

Comment: I want to create current date in "America/Juneau" time zone, So first I create date with system time zone then convert it to  "America/Juneau" time zone. please let me know if you have any better way to do so.

Comment: But `NSDate` doesn't have a timezone, so any timezone information is lost when you return the date.  Using the same date formatter to do date > string > date doesn't achieve anything, surely?

Comment: Thanks @Droppy, As explained by you this question is not proper. So I will delete it to make forum clean.

Answer (score 2):

```
[[NSTimeZone *yourTimeZone*] secondsFromGMTForDate:*yourDate*]
```

With this method, you can get `secondsFromGMTForDate` for a particular `timezone` which is also adjusted with daylight saving.

You can use this offset to create a date object in your timezone and show the *weekview* accordingly.

Comment: I had removed the date formatter and applied timezone offset, It works for me. Please improve your answer with UTC to user timezone offset calculation with current date to make it answer :)